# Server reverts to PPP Adapter IP, breaks sql connections

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, sql-server

Here is the issue.  Server 1 loses connection via sql to Server 2.  Each time this happens I notice that pinging Server 2 from Server 1 shows it resolves the IP to the address of its PPP Adapter IP.  The ping also times out. I then flush the dns, ping again -- which resolves to a different/working connection and sql works.

Is this as easy as disabling that adapter or should I be setting it not to use that address somewhere?  I suppose I could also change the sql connection to an individual IP instead of the server name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the PPP adapter IP not the right address for server 2?  Sounds like you have a DNS failure of some sort.